# Tableau: How to change multiple field names

Tags: preprocessing, sql, tableau

From SQL server I imported multiple tables that each have multiple fields. Unfortunately the field names are not that descriptive (data is originally from SAP) but I have a separate Excel file that has description for all the field names.

Is there a way how I could rename multiple fields once by using the Excel file? Renaming them one by one would be too slow way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have/know python pandas? An easy why would be too load it into pandas and do the modifications there.

df= pd.read(excel)

AFTER Comment

OR:

You can rename columns in SQL with AS - if that is possible with your SAP import. To create a (semi-) automated Logic should be easy with a decent Texteditor,

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know nor have python pandas.